# Reset ranking in snowflake ordered by date and id for identifying repeat calls sequence

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, rank

Need help in snowflake.
I need to identify which is the first and last repeat call within 7 days by a customer partitioned by customer_id and ordered by call_time.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOt7b.png)

"Customer_id" is a unique id for each customer who has called at "Call_time". "REPEAT_CALLS_7_DAYS_FLAG" identifies calls that were made within 7 days of previous call by ordering the data in ascending order of call_time for each customer_id and finding the difference between the current call_time and the previous call_time. If the difference is within 7 days then tagged as 1 else 0.
I need to rank these calls as shown in "Repeat_calls_rank" column to identify which is the first & Last call within a series of 7 days repeat call and create the column "tag" as shown in the image.

I tried
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Customer_id, REPEAT_CALLS_7_DAYS_FLAG = 1 ORDER BY Call_time asc) as repeat_calls_7_days_rank
but i do not get the desired outcome because it ranks all calls tagged as 1 without restarting when there is a new call placed beyond 7 days of previous calls. i.e restart ranking when "REPEAT_CALLS_7_DAYS_FLAG" hits 0 in the ordered data.

I need "Repeat_calls_rank" and "tag" column as shown in the image by customer_id

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Answer (score 0):

With a partial set of data

```
with fake_data(call_time, customer_id) as (
    select * from values
        ('2023-04-07 12:02'::datetime, 1),
        ('2023-04-07 13:28'::datetime, 1),
        ('2023-04-07 18:35'::datetime, 1),
        ('2023-04-10 11:32'::datetime, 1),
        ('2023-05-03 17:31'::datetime, 1),
        ('2023-05-09 10:22'::datetime, 1)
), seven_days as (
    select *
        ,lag(call_time) over (partition by customer_id order by call_time) as lag_call
        ,datediff('seconds', lag_call, call_time) as diff_s
        ,diff_s/(86400) as diff_d
        ,iff(diff_d < 7, 1, 0) as repeat_calls_7days_flag
    from fake_data
), seven_day_rank as ( 
    select   
        call_time
        ,customer_id
        ,repeat_calls_7days_flag
        ,row_number() over (partition by customer_id, repeat_calls_7days_flag order by call_time) as rn
        ,iff(repeat_calls_7days_flag = 1, rn, null) as repeat_calls_7_days_rank
    from seven_days
), grouped as (
    select * exclude rn
        ,CONDITIONAL_TRUE_EVENT(repeat_calls_7days_flag = 0) over(partition by customer_id order by call_time) as grp
    from seven_day_rank
), groups_ranked as (
    select *
        ,row_number() over (partition by customer_id, grp order by call_time) -1 as repeat_calls_rank
    from grouped
), max_groups as (
    select * 
        ,max(nullifzero(repeat_calls_rank)) over (partition by customer_id, grp) as max_group_rank
    from groups_ranked
)
select
    * exclude (grp, max_group_rank)
    ,case 
        when repeat_calls_rank = 1 and repeat_calls_rank = max_group_rank 
            then 'First&Last repeat call'
        when repeat_calls_rank = 1
            then 'First repeat call'
        when repeat_calls_rank = max_group_rank
            then 'Last repeat call'
    end as tag
from max_groups
```

gives:

| CALL_TIME | CUSTOMER_ID | REPEAT_CALLS_7DAYS_FLAG | REPEAT_CALLS_7_DAYS_RANK | REPEAT_CALLS_RANK | TAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-07 12:02:00.000 | 1 | 0 |  | 0 | null |
| 2023-04-07 13:28:00.000 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | First repeat call |
| 2023-04-07 18:35:00.000 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | null |
| 2023-04-10 11:32:00.000 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 3 | Last repeat call |
| 2023-05-03 17:31:00.000 | 1 | 0 |  | 0 | null |
| 2023-05-09 10:22:00.000 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 1 | First&Last repeat call |